# Regular expression that matches between quotes

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I want to write a regular expression that match string in quotes except quotes in my quotes.
For example: 
My string:
"Good programm\",\"pls help"

I want to get:
Good programm\",\"pls help

Comment: Regexes is not good for nested structures

Comment: Need it with regular expressions only :(

Comment: You can try something like this: `[^\"]*(\(.*\))[^\"]*`

Comment: It doesn't work. Testing in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2):

Try `(?<=").*(?=")` check online: http://regexr.com?349d2

Comment: Nice, it works! Sorry, but what if we have string like "good"morning \"nice"
i need to get good morning \" nice

Comment: For this example please use regexp replace method for delete all not right quotes. RegEx to replace `(?<!\\)"` See http://regexr.com?349e3

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have nested structures you can try this:

```
(?<=")(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*(?=")
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?349cs)

`(?<=")` [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), ensures there is a " before the match (Try if it is working for you, in Regexr it is.)

`(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")` [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): matches either a character that is not a ", or a " that is escaped (ensured by the lookbehind `(?<=\\)`).

`*` The character from the alternation is [matches 0 or more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

`(?=")` [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), ensures there is a " after the match

But be careful: It matches across newlines and also between escaped ", when there are no non escaped quotes available.

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?349d5)

Comment: Sorry, how to make your regular expression works more than one time.
See http://regexr.com?349db 
Need to extract - 'Good p' and 'rogramm\",\"pls help'

Comment: Thank you!but we need to skip such symbols like /n /t /0 and so on/ Help us))

Comment: @Sunstrike: Put them into the negated character class like this: `[^"\n\t\0]`. The "and so on" part you have to define by yourself.